# Can you create a pivot table in the same sheet as the data its referencing?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Is it possible to have a pivot table on the same sheet as the data it's referencing in a Google Sheet?

At the moment if I create a pivot table it always creates a new sheet.

Comment: No, you can't (and pivot tables are ~evil~). Learn array formula. You can put a lot of pivot-like table in the same sheet using regular functions. It takes practice but worths the effort if you do lots of data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the cells of the pivot table you want to copy and then copy and paste it in the spreadsheet or sheet where you want it (or select desired cells and  use **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>X</kbd>** and then **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>** to move it). If you want to, you can then delete the pivot table sheet.

Comment: would this retain the "live" / "editable" nature of the pivot table ?